# Can i give alignment in the picker view's data?

Tags: iphone

i am new in the iphone application development.i want to provide the Alignment in the content of picker view so how it is possible.i want to provide "centre" alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

delegate method is your friend in this case) you can create your own view (UILabel for example) and set it properties as you want.